# rails inner join using belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inner-join

```
class A < ActiveRecord

end

class B < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :a
end
```

Based on the above relation, I would like to do a join:

```
SELECT A.* from A WHERE A.account_number = B.account_id
```

I tried this

```
@as = A.joins("INNER JOIN b ON b.account_id = A.account_number")
@as.each do |a|
```

I get this error in the last line (@as.each do |a|) above:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "b" does not exist
```

What am I missing here? Please advise.

Comment: Please add has many or your required association in class A. , like has_many :bs

Comment: You need to pluralize the table name

Comment: @DeepakMahakale pluralize model, table name is always pluralized

Comment: Your example SQL looks backwards versus your model. Your model says B belongs to A (and implying that A has many Bs), but your SQL is finding many As associated with one B. So your `class B` should have `has_many :as` and `class A` should have `belongs_to :b`. You don't need the `join` statement since Rails does that work for you when you define your model correctly. You can just write, `@b.as.each ...` if `@b` is a B item.

Comment: Hi Lurker - thank you for the inputs. For a given record in B, I would like to access fields f1 and f2 which are present only in A. Could you please guide me on how I could do that?

Comment: Also, can I read f1 and f2 for each record of B without having a relationship defined inside A? B belongs to A; A has no relation defined to B. Can I achieve my goal with this existing one way relation? Please advise.

Comment: A `B` has many `A`s, so you need to pick one first. For example, `@b.as.each do |a| ... a.f1 ....` etc. If you don't define the relationship between `A` and `B`, then you cannot access the associated `A` records, and thus their attributes, from a `B` record. Maybe you should explain more clearly in your question what you are trying to achieve and give more specific examples.